# Attribute use errors with named arguments, but not as unnamed?

Tags: vb.net

I can't get named arguments to work on this attribute. Works with-out name arguments but not with?
Not sure what I'm missing?

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30516 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.    UniversalTestProject_VB G:\Dev\FrozenElephant\SymbioticORM\SymbioticUniversalTests\UniversalTestProject_VB\ExampleUnitTests\Immutable\ImmutableRelationships_Indentity_UsingRelationOneToMany.vb    118 Active
```

Usage (named fails, unnamed works; 2nd line):

```
    <DatabaseRelationOneToMany(TableName:="IdentityOneToManyChild", ParentColumnName:="ParentId", ChildColumnName:="ChildId", DeferredLoad:=False)>
<DatabaseRelationOneToMany("IdentityOneToManyChild", "ParentId", "ChildId", False)>
Public Property Children As IList(Of IdentityOneToManyChild)
    Get
        Return m_Children
    End Get
    Set(value As IList(Of IdentityOneToManyChild))
        m_Children = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Attribute:

```
<CLSCompliant(True)>
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple:=False, Inherited:=False)>
Public NotInheritable Class DatabaseRelationOneToManyAttribute
    Inherits DatabaseRelationAttribute

    Private m_TableName As String
    Private m_DeferredLoad As Boolean
    Private m_RelationSql As String
    Private m_ParentColumnName As String
    Private m_ChildColumnName As String


    Public Sub New(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal parentColumnName As String, ByVal childColumnName As String, ByVal deferredLoad As Boolean)
        m_TableName = tableName
        m_DeferredLoad = deferredLoad
        m_ParentColumnName = parentColumnName
        m_ChildColumnName = childColumnName
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal parentColumnName As String, ByVal childColumnName As String, ByVal deferredLoad As Boolean, ByVal relationSql As String)
        m_TableName = tableName
        m_DeferredLoad = deferredLoad
        m_ParentColumnName = parentColumnName
        m_RelationSql = relationSql
        m_ChildColumnName = childColumnName
    End Sub

    Public Property TableName() As String
        Get
            Return m_TableName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_TableName = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property DeferredLoad As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_DeferredLoad
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_DeferredLoad = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property RelationSql As String
        Get
            Return m_RelationSql
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_RelationSql = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ParentColumnName As String
        Get
            Return m_ParentColumnName
        End Get
        Set
            m_ParentColumnName = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ChildColumnName As String
        Get
            Return m_ChildColumnName
        End Get
        Set
            m_ChildColumnName = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Appears to work in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DatabaseRelationOneToMany(tableName:"AAAAA",parentColumnName:"BBBB",childColumnName:"CCCCCC",deferredLoad:false)]
        public IList<Object> Children { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public sealed class DatabaseRelationOneToManyAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private string m_TableName;
        private bool m_DeferredLoad;
        private string m_RelationSql;
        private string m_ParentColumnName;
        private string m_ChildColumnName;

       public DatabaseRelationOneToManyAttribute(string tableName, string parentColumnName, string childColumnName, bool deferredLoad)
        {
            m_TableName = tableName;
            m_DeferredLoad = deferredLoad;
            m_ParentColumnName = parentColumnName;
            m_ChildColumnName = childColumnName;
        }

        public DatabaseRelationOneToManyAttribute(string tableName, string parentColumnName, string childColumnName, bool deferredLoad, string relationSql)
        {
            m_TableName = tableName;
            m_DeferredLoad = deferredLoad;
            m_ParentColumnName = parentColumnName;
            m_RelationSql = relationSql;
            m_ChildColumnName = childColumnName;
        }


        public string TableName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_TableName;
            }
            set
            {
                m_TableName = value;
            }
        }


        public bool DeferredLoad
        {
            get
            {
                return m_DeferredLoad;
            }
            set
            {
                m_DeferredLoad = value;
            }
        }

        public string RelationSql
        {
            get
            {
                return m_RelationSql;
            }
            set
            {
                m_RelationSql = value;
            }
        }

        public string ParentColumnName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ParentColumnName;
            }
            set
            {
                m_ParentColumnName = value;
            }
        }

        public string ChildColumnName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ChildColumnName;
            }
            set
            {
                m_ChildColumnName = value;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Taking a read of [Attribute Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-parameters) seems to suggest that the named parameters are used to map to Properties of the class rather than the parameters of the constructor

Comment: yes, I think your right, if true the error message in wrong. that said the properties exists. I'm show the entire attribute code.

Comment: I wonder if this works in C#? I'll have to try

Comment: c# version works, maybe it's a vb.net compiler bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that confusion arises due to both the constructor parameters and the property names being named the same (in a case-insensitive sense) and that VB.Net has never supported named arguments for Attribute constructors.  However it has used the named argument syntax (`ParameterName:=value`) for publicly scoped fields and properties that are *promoted* to the constructor for Attributes.

```
PromotedPropertyName:=value
```

> c# version works, maybe it's a vb.net compiler bug?

C# prior to version 4 (VS2010) did not support [Named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) except for the *promoted* fields and properties in Attributes.  The syntax used is:

```
PromotedPropertyName = value
```

This syntax is still used in C# for the *promoted* fields and properties in addition to named arguments for the Attribute constructor's parameters; however the C# syntax for passing named arguments is:

ParameterName : value

Your first usage:

```
<DatabaseRelationOneToMany(TableName:="IdentityOneToManyChild", ParentColumnName:="ParentId", ChildColumnName:="ChildId", DeferredLoad:=False)>
```

is passing only the *promoted* properties and generates the error because there is no parameter-less constructor signature defined.

It would be valid if you added a parameter-less constructor or deleted the two defined constructors so that the compiler would add its own parameter-less public constructor.

Comment: thanks, adding the default empty constructor fixes the problem, which makes sense if it's not really using a constructor. I also know that the properties must have setters, ran into that issue before too, still don't understand why the c# version works and not the vb.net. Also the vb.net error message is definitely wrong.

Comment: @EricSchneider, the err message was " no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments" that for the case of supplying only promoted Property arguments is correct; there was no parameter-less constructor.  This whole field/property being promoted to the constructor stuff just messes with one's sense of what is correct.

Comment: the error is wrong, there is a constructor that matches the number of arguments. I had four arguments and there is a constructor for it. If it had said I needed a parameter-less constructor then we would not be having this conversation.